# ASP.NET local resources' Culture property scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, resources

I have an ASP.NET 5 application and I am currently implementing a localization.

Resources are located in the ASP.NET folder `App_LocalResources` and everything is working properly. At least, while it is in development phase. I have the following `ResourceCultureFilterAttribute`:

```
using MyProject.App_LocalResources;

public class ResourceCultureFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string language = GetClientLanguageFromCookiesDoesntMatter();
        var culture = new CultureInfo(language);

        GlobalResources.Culture = culture;
    }
}
```

And now I access it this way in Razor view:

```
@GlobalResources.SomeResourceName
```

Now, I am worrying that `Culture` propery of auto-generated resource class is `static`.
Does it mean that this property is set **per-thread** or **per-application-pool** (please, specify the right one) but not **per-user**?
If yes, then several users will just override and use the single value and definitely cause problems to localization.

I know how to fix it by replacing direct access by:

```
@GlobalResources.ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceName", 
    new CultureInfo(GetClientLanguageFromCookiesDoesntMatter());
```

But, maybe, there is a more proper solution - something important that I just don't see or don't know. Maybe, there is a special property like `CurrentUserCulture`, special multi-user resource class, attribute or something else to provide a simple and plain localization into an ASP.NET project.

Comment: Since `static` is type-bound, it is set for the whole `AppDomain`, not per thread.

Comment: Recently asp.net team have implemented their variant of localization: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization, it may be relavent for you.

Comment: One more thing - you can change `new CultureInfo(language);` to `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language)` since it doesn't require creation of whole `CultureInfo` object.

Comment: @OleksiiAza Thanks. I will take a look at this for sure!

Comment: @Kamo Thank you for clarification. Special thanks about telling about `GetCultureInfo` - I would never know about it's existence :)